# libqrencode - Segmentation fault couldn't read "qrspec.c"

Tags: c, pthreads, aix, powerpc, xlc

I previously made this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107183/qrencode-segmentation-fault-core-dumped)  and got a light at the end of the tunnel by the response that I got. But now that I found the problem, I don't understand it. I don't have root priv. Whenever I run the program I get segmentation fault and a core file. When I analyse it with dbx I get this

```
reading symbolic information ...

Segmentation fault in QRspec_newFrame at line 546 in file "" ($t1)
couldn't read "qrspec.c"
```

How come he can't find qrspec.c if that file was included on the process of generating the lib? (I wasn't involved on that process so I have no idea if it went 100% but I gave the .tar with all the files). Also that file belongs to libqrencode.

Compiling:

```
xlc_r7 -g qrgen.c -lqrencode -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include
```

I'm starting to bealive it can't find the file because there is a .so symbolic link missing on the /usr/local/lib folder. Could that be it? (Only .a , .la and .so.3 in there)

I think my problem is similiar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory) but I can't install the lib again unless that is the real problem.

Machine: Unix AIX powerpc model: IBM,9117-MMB
xlc version: 12.01.0000.0000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem... The installation of the lib generated problems and caused the symbolic links to exist as a simple file and the library just wasn't there...

This is the missing file "/usr/local/lib/libqrencode.so.3.4.4" which is the code itself... I was looking at the files and didn't notice it because there was a file called libqrencode.so.3.4 but this file was supose to be a symbolic link to libqrencode.so.3.4.4 since libqrencode.so.3.4.4 didn't exist, instead of the symbolic link failing, it created a empty file with that same name...

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you need to tell dbx where to find your source files

From man dbx
       -I Directory
            (Uppercase i) Includes directory specified by the Directory variable in the list of directories searched for source files. The default is to look for source files in the following directories:
              *    The directory the source file was located in when it was compiled. This directory is searched only if the compiler placed the source path in the object.
              *    The current directory.
              *    The directory where the program is currently located.